# tensorboard dev - non-interactively

Tags: tensorboard

How do I use the tensorboard dev upload (uploading to the server), when I cannot set it up interactively (i.e. getting and pasting the token)?

I did not find a reference on the `tensorboard` command.

Comment: I overcame it by periodically rsyncing the tb logdir to a directory accessible in an interactive session